# How to combine/concatenate videos stored in AWS S3 bucket based on title of the file name

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I am using a service that allows me to record videos that get automatically pushed to a folder (submissions) in an S3 bucket. There are multiple videos however they need to be grouped together and concatenated so the output is one video per group.

So, basically, any tips on how I can take videos based on the title and stitch them together?

Example:

Submissions folder will have:

```
a-100-2.mp4
a-200-6.mp4
b-123-5.mp4
```

Expected output in processed folder:

```
a.mp4     - (both 'a' videos get stitched together)
b.mp4     - (only 'b' gets sent over since there is only one video.)
```

Thanks in advance!

**Edit: Some additional and detailed information below if it helps.**

The files will be labeled with:
{name}-{location}-{video_token}-{stream_token}.mp4

Need help creating a script or process that will concatenate the videos using the procedure outlined below:

**Processing rules (back end):**

1. Check if videos have same {video_token} in ‘submissions folder’. If so, keep the newest one and delete old ones.
2. Take all videos in ‘submissions folder’ with same {name} and {location} in title and concatenate the videos. Save output video to a new folder in the bucket labeled as the {location} for the folder name. 
   Output file name: 
   {name}-{location}-{year}.{mp4}.

**EXAMPLE:**

**Submissions folder:**
joey-toronto-001-354.mp4

joey-toronto-001-241.mp4 - this will be deleted

joey-toronto-103-452.mp4

alex-montreal-352-232.mp4

alex-montreal-452-223.mp4

**Resulting output:**

Toronto folder:

Joey-toronto-2020.mp4

Montreal folder:

Alex-montreal-2020.mp4

Comment: Launch a container using ECS, list the objects in S3, pull the relevant MP4s from S3 onto local disk, use ffmpeg to concatenate the videos, and then write the resulting MP4 back to S3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Clip Stitching - Amazon Elastic Transcoder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/clip-stitching.html).

The **Amazon Elastic Transcoder** allows you to specify multiple input files from S3 (and even time ranges within those files) and output them to a single video file. It's just a matter of providing a list of input sources.

I used that for: [Automated video editing with YOU as the star! | AWS Machine Learning Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/automated-video-editing-with-you-as-the-star/)

There is some sample code on that page that calls Elastic Transcoder:

```py
'''
The inputs array now looks like:
[
  {'Key': 'trainers.mp4', 'TimeSpan': {'StartTime': '99.8', 'Duration': '1.68'}},
  {'Key': 'trainers.mp4', 'TimeSpan': {'StartTime': '127.52', 'Duration': '4.24'}},
  ...
]
'''

# Call Amazon Elastic Transcoder to stitch together a new video
client = boto3.client('elastictranscoder', region_name = 'ap-southeast-2')

job = client.create_job(
  PipelineId = '...',
  Inputs=inputs,
  Output={'Key': person_to_find + '.mp4', 'PresetId': '...'}
)
```

It might also be possible with **AWS Elemental MediaConvert**.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation! - when you mentioned providing a list of input sources, can they be dynamically pulled or do I have to manually code in the file names? - Sorry if my questions are basic, new to cloud computing world =)

Comment: My program (shown above) takes a list of Keys (filenames) and ranges. You can programmatically provide that data. So, your program will first look through the list of videos, figure out which ones to join together, then pass that list to the `create_job()` command to create a single output video. Repeat for each output video you want. You can pre-create a 'pipeline' that just sits there waiting for work (no charge for the pipeline). Then, your program submits jobs to the pipeline.