# How can I stream all video files in s3 a bucket consecutively to a vue app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3

I have security footage stored in 2 min `.mov` files in an s3 bucket, named by the time they were created (eg "02-03-2021--09:02:53")

How would I go about streaming these videos into a vue app consecutively from a time `x`?

IE. User selects time `y`, app starts streaming videos from time `x` closest to `y` and go over to the next video until the user does some action to stop it.

Would not say I need help with the time and video selecting logic, I am just pretty new with web and vue and struggling to find resources of how to stream videos in an s3 bucket into a vue app.

pseudo code:

```
for file in bucket_filtered_by_time_greater_than_yish:
  <video 
     muted  width="100%" height="100%"
     id="vid1"
     src=file
  >
  </video>

<script>

// user selects y = 5 seconds

x= 0seconds   ---> so we select the first video with some logic
y= 5seconds   ---> start 5 seconds into the first video

document.getElementById('vid1').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  this.currentTime = 5; ---> difference between y and x
}, false);

</script>
```

Any resource would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would use Amazon Elemental to join these files into one file and then stream them using S3.
[https://aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/](https://aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/)

Comment: Agree with Shelly here. You will have to do something like this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/serverless-video-on-demand-vod-workflow/

Or manage it at the app later where you download full files and then clip and concat at the app layer. - Not adviced.

Comment: Also, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62269331/how-to-combine-concatenate-videos-stored-in-aws-s3-bucket-based-on-title-of-the